# Having issues merging time series data

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Having issues merging data from multiple sheets from within same excel file.

```
 2008: Data
UNI    DEP      ADDRESBR
6      24065037 225 Franklin Street
17     416952   100 North Gay Street
361391  3756    1717 South College
blank   81651   215 South 6th Street

2009 : Data
UNI     DEP-2009      ADDRESBR
6      20624948  225 Franklin Street
17      471803   100 North Gay Street
361391  3891     1717 South College
180886  100277   215 South 6th Street
493224  1683     2315 Bentcreek Road
```

The goal is to combine all the sheet values, into the first sheet, just appending the year_dep as a new column. The issue I am having is the blank information from sheet1, and trying to match address, uniq from each colum. 
Final result should look like this.

```
UNI DEPSUMBR    ADDRESBR            DEP-2009   DEP-n
6      20624948 225 Franklin Street  20624948
17      471803  100 North Gay Street  471803
361391  3891    1717 South College   3891
180886  100277  215 South 6th Street ...
493224  1683    2315 Bentcreek Road  ...
```

Can anyone help, as to how I would do this in python? The goal is to have a final dataset that accounts for dep per year appended as a column.The trouble that I am having is matching dep value per year with respective UNI#

Comment: I'm not sure how one could help you without seeing what you've tried. However if you haven't tried anything yet, start with this link - https://pbpython.com/excel-file-combine.html

Comment: according to the example, the final df is sheet 2, i would request you to edit the question a little to show what exactly you want. Also I have a feeling you want [`combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

Comment: Your final result is simply `sheet2`. Not sure why do you have to merge. Can you come up with a [MCVE] ?

Comment: Hopefully that helps, I am pretty new python